# Swift: editActionsForRowAtIndexPath can't access indexPathForSelectedRow?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexpath

When accessing `tableView(tableView,editActionsForRowAtIndexPath)` I want to call a function on the previously selected `UITableViewCell`, but `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` is returning `nil`.

Here is the code I am using. The block inside the if statement does not run and `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` returns a `nil` value.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        if let selectedRow = activityTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            updateCell(atIndexPath: selectedRow)
        }

        var rowActions = [UITableViewRowAction]()

        ....

        return rowActions

}
```

Comment: Just declare a member variable to cache the indexPath of the last selected cell and use that.

Comment: I'm confused, there's already an indexPath parameter for you in the function declaration? Use that?

Comment: The indexPath parameter in the function is the indexPath of the swiped cell. I'm trying to get the indexPath of the previously selected cell. Either way, why is indexPathForSelectedRow returning nil?